# To Find the OverLapping dateTime

Tags: c#, linq

I need to find the Overlapping dates and time using linq

example:

Scenario 1

i will define the date 1/4/2015 and 9/4/2015 and time span of 05:12 to 10:56

and i will define one more date range like 1/4/2015 to 2/4/2015 and time span of 11:45 to 15:67

and this should get added to DB as it is not lies in the 1st defined date.

if i add 1/4/2015 and 5/4/2015 and time span of 09:12 to 10:00 this should not allow to save in db.

Scenario 2:

And in the UI page i need to fetch these content which in between the date and time span with respect to server time.

Consider Current time is 12:00 now it has to pic 1/4/2015 to 2/4/2015 and time span of 11:45 to 15:67 date range record.

can any one help me out how to write the logic in linq.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that your example in Scenario 1 represents 6 periods of time, one for every day, that each start and end at the same time of day?

Comment: Hi can any one help me out for second scenario 2